# How to represent / plot the efficiency and the optimal solutions of my code in graphs in cplex?

Tags: cplex

How to represent the efficiency of my code in graphs? I want to generate many graphs regarding the efficiency and the convergence of optimum solution of my model in cplex ?? what is the benefits and concept of the black statistical graph  that appears in statistical window during run my code?

Comment: @.  Alexfleischer

Answer (score 0):

We call this graph the progress chart.

See IDE and OPL > IDE and OPL > CPLEX Studio IDE > IDE Tutorials > Understanding solving statistics and progress (MP models) > Examining the statistics and progress chart (MP)

in CPLEX documentation

[image]